# Is the first difference of a strongly stationary process stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, differencing

Let $X_t$ be a strongly stationary time series. Is the first-order difference process $\nabla X_t$ always stationary?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, could you explicitly define $\nabla X_t$ in terms of $X_t$? Do you perhaps mean $\nabla X_t:=X_{t}-X_{t-1}$? In that case we talk about a first-differenced process, and that is kind of the opposite of an integrated one. If you integrated $X_t$, you get $Y_t:=\sum_{\tau=1}^t X_\tau$.

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes sorry i mixed up integration and differentiation. I just edited the question as I was indeed referring to $\nabla X_t$ as differentiation i.e. $\nabla X_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$

Comment: The commonly used symbol for differencing (not quite the same as differentiation) is $\Delta$ rather than $\nabla$ (but that does not change the substance).